# Compute $\int_{|z|=1}|z^5-1|^2|dz|$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration

Question: Compute $\int_{|z|=1}|z^5-1|^2|dz|$.

My attempt: Let $z=e^{i\theta}$, then $|dz|=|ie^{i\theta}|d\theta=1$.  So,

\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1}|z^5-1|^2|dz| &= \int_0^{2\pi}|e^{i5\theta}-1|^2d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}[\cos^25\theta-2\cos5\theta+1+\sin^25\theta]d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}(2-2\cos5\theta)d\theta\\
&= [2\theta-\frac{2}{5}\sin5\theta]|_0^{2\pi}\\
&= 4\pi-\frac{2}{5}\sin10\pi\\
&= 4 \pi
\end{align}

I suppose I was thinking I made some algebra/calculus error somewhere because I got the same answer when I computed $\int_{|z|=1}|z-1|^2|dz|$, but I couldn't find an error.

Comment: Interesting observation. The same algebra shows you can replace $5$ by any $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Oh, duh, right, because it'll always come down to, regardless of what natural number we raise $z$ to, $\sin2\pi n=0$.  Thank you :)

Comment: right, and in this case we can even let $n$ be any non-zero integer (i.e negative as well).

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  If you'd want to turn your comments into a one or two line answer, I would be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: The coincidence may seem less coincidental if you note that $\int_0^{2\pi}|az^n+bz^m|^2|dz|=2\pi(|a|^2+|b|^2)$ for any $a,b\in\Bbb C$ and $n,m\in\Bbb Z$ with $n\ne m$. (When you're older: this all has to do with orthogonality, whatever that is...)

Comment: The command of Mathematica `Integrate[Abs[Exp[I*t]^5 - 1]^2, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]` answers $4\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact same computation holds for any non-zero integer $n$ (negative as well).

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitrary integrable function $f$ and non-zero integer $n$ is the value of the integral
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{in\theta}) \, d\theta = \frac 1n \int_0^{2n\pi}f(e^{i\tau}) \, d\tau = \int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{i\tau}) d\tau
$$
independent of $n$. (First substitute $n\theta = \tau$, then use that $\tau \mapsto e^{i\tau}$ is $2\pi$-periodic.)

Applied to your case,
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}|e^{in\theta}-1|^2 \, d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}|e^{i\tau}-1|^2d \, \tau = \int_0^{2\pi} (2-2\cos(\tau)) \, d\tau = 4 \pi + 0
$$
for $n \in \Bbb Z \setminus \{ 0 \}$.